# translating a PHP variable to a JQuery one.

Tags: php, jquery

I have a PHP variable called `$finalprice`

If I echo it out from PHP it returns `147`

I then want to manipulate it and do some calculations with JQuery, so I do the following:

```
 $('#childseat').change(function() {
        $('#childseatadd').show();
            var price = "<?php echo number_format($finalprice, 2); ?>";
            alert(price);
            var numberofboostseat = $(this).val();
            alert(numberofboostseat);
            var numofdays = "<?php echo $length->days; ?>";
            alert(numofdays);
            var boostcost = Number(3) * Number(numofdays);
            var boosttotal = Number(numberofboostseat) * Number(boostcost);
            var newprice = Number(price) + Number(boosttotal);
            $('.price').html(newprice);
        });
```

The rest of my calculations are fine, however these lines:

```
var price = "<?php echo number_format($finalprice, 2); ?>";
alert(price);
```

The alert returns **140** not **147**, and I have no clue as to why I'm loosing 7.... any suggestions?

Comment: Please check it might be 140 stored in `$finalprice` . View the source of the page then you can get the problem.

Comment: alert("<?php echo $finalprice ?>"); If it is 147 than it's true mystery to me.

Comment: Did you try with different values??

Comment: Am trying it with a few things now, this seems to be the only one that looses value

Comment: @ObjectiveJ try this instead `number_format($finalprice, 2, '.');`

Answer (score 0):

The following is an example of a php variable in jquery:

```
  <script>
$(function(){
   $("a#yeah").click(function(){
           $.ajax({
        url: "ajax.php?action=yeah&id=<?php echo $id?>",
        success: function(html){
         $("a#yeah").html("your cool")
                   }
     })
   })


})</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check first what you get in `$finalprice` in `alert` like:

```
alert("<?php echo number_format($finalprice, 2); ?>");
```

Also check, that you do not `change` the `value` of `$finalprice` by you `code`.